# Cantor set code does not give expected output

Tags: python, recursion

I have some bugs in cantor set code that I cannot locate. The idea is that given array of numbers you recursively remove 1/3 of middle elements and recurse on two sides and repeat until certain threshold.

Here is the code

```
import math

full = list(range(80))
l = list(range(80))

threshold = 2

def printl():
    for i in full:
        if i in l:
            print("*", end='')
        else:
            print(" ", end='')
    print()

def cantor(lo, hi):
    lowi = math.ceil( (hi-lo) * 1/3 + lo)
    highi = int( (hi-lo) * 2/3 + lo)

    if len(l[lo:hi]) < threshold:
        return

    printl()
    del l[lowi:highi]
    cantor(lo, lowi)
    cantor(lowi+1, hi)
```

cantor(0, len(l)-1)

I get super weird result, not sure why...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tricky problem -- I calculated the pieces and recursively zip'd them together into an array which I then dump to the terminal:

```
from math import log

def cantor(length, threshold):
    if length >= threshold:
        sequence = cantor(length // 3, threshold)
        blanks = [" " * (length // 3)] * int(log(length, 3) + 1)  # estimate and let zip toss extras
        return ["*" * length] + [a + b + c for a, b, c in zip(sequence, blanks, sequence)]

    return []

length = 81
threshold = 1

print(*cantor(length, threshold), sep='\n')
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
*********************************************************************************
***************************                           ***************************
*********         *********                           *********         *********
***   ***         ***   ***                           ***   ***         ***   ***
* *   * *         * *   * *                           * *   * *         * *   * *
>
```

Comment: Looks good, but how do I extract only last layer? I need only last layer for a given threshold

Comment: @YohanRoth, where in your code or explanation is the last layer issue addressed?  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: In my code I tried to have variable l to contain the last layer answer. But yes, I did not clearly specify that I need last layer. Thus I accepted the answer.  If you can help me with it - I will appreciate. but you dont need to

Comment: @YohanRoth, if you do `print(cantor(length, threshold)[-1])` you'll see that the last element of the result of the `cantor()` call is the last layer.  Note: the output is only clean if the input is clean -- i.e. I chose 81 for a reason.  If you try 80, the result will be a bit messy and you'll need to augment the code slightly to make things line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the order of processing the slices to go from last to first because recursing into the lower indexes will invalidate the positions that the prior recursion has for lowi and hi:

```
cantor(lowi+1, hi)
cantor(lo, lowi)
cantor(0, len(l)-1)
```

*You may want to check the end of ranges in your subscripts because the end of a range is exclusive.  i.e. l[2:7] does not include index #7.*

Comment: changing orders didn't help :(

Comment: I looked up the Cantor set and I don't think you'll be able to print the lines as illustrated on wikipedia while you're recursing through the elements because the recursion will always go to the bottom depth on one side before popping back to the caller.  So either you left or right part is going to be completely hollowed out before the opposite side starts to be processed.  And this happens at every level of the recursion.  You probably need to build an array of lines and print them at the end of the process